# e.target.value is undefined reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can some help I am not understanding why i am getting this error.Is because that the data being passed is not visible or it has to do with how i handled change event

```
class Signup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            step:1,
            email:'',
            password:'',
          
        };
    }
  
    handleChange = input => e => {
        this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
    };
    render() 
        const { email, password,} = this.state;
        const values = { email, password, }

       switch (step) {
           case 1:
           return(
               <UserDetails  handleChange={this.handleChange()} values={values}/>

               )
           case 2:
               return (
                   <Verification  />

               )
           default:


       }
    }
}

export default Signup;


function UserDetails({handleChange,values}) {
   
    return (
        <section >
            <div >
                <div>
                    <form action="">                     
                        <div>
                            <label 
                            <input
                              value={values.email} onChange={handleChange('email')} />
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           
                            <input
                               value={values.password} onChange={handleChange('password')} />
                        </div>                        
                        <button onClick={Continue}>Sign Up</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}

export default UserDetails;
```

Can anyone please help to understand cause i don't understand what is causing the error yet i have handled change correctly

Comment: simply why are you using component based approach in react kindly use functional approach and see how it will be easy to code. Change few lines of code with functional component and see the magic of react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UserDetails, you're calling `handleChange('password')` on every change event without taking the event. You're just calling with the string `'password'`. To fix this, you need a couple of changes.

First, in **UserDetails.js**

```
   <input value={values.password} onChange={(e) => handleChange('password', e)} />
```

Second, in **Signup.js** you need to **append** to the current state

```
    handleChange = (input, e) => {
        this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, [input]: e.target.value }));
    };
```

[See React docs for more information](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Answer (score 0):

When the interpreter is gonna parse the code it is gonna run the function immediately since you are calling the function rather than passing a reference to the function

```
<input value={values.password} onChange={handleChange('password')} />
```

Change your code to this,

```
<input value={values.password} onChange={(e) => handleChange('password', e)} />
```

or

```
<input value={values.password} onChange={handleChange.bind('password', e)} />
```

And change your function from,

```
handleChange = input => e => {
        this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
    };
```

to this,

```
handleChange = (input, e) => {
        this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, [input]: e.target.value }));
    };
```

Comment: np, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

`handleChange` is a partial function and you are evaluating it with empty input before passing it to `UserDetails`

Change

```
<UserDetails  handleChange={this.handleChange()} values={values}/>
```

to

```
<UserDetails  handleChange={this.handleChange} values={values}/>
```

and it should work just fine